# How do you use Compass with Symfony2.2 + Assetic

Tags: symfony, sass, compass-sass, assetic, symfony-2.2

There are a bunch of questions related to Assetic and SASS or Compass, but nobody actually answers how to use Assetic with Compass and what the correct directory structure should be.

How do I set up my asset directories to achieve full compass functionality and benefits (auto-generated sprites, sass language, compass plugins) and have the ability to use assetic to serve up only the assets needed for that specific view. And what is the correct config to handle this setup?

How do I do this?

Comment: 2. Use assetic's compass filter to compile the sass files.

Comment: If you use assetics compass filter than where are u putting the scss files? cant put them in their corresponding bundles as far as i know...

Comment: Why use yui_compressor when Sass/Compass already compresses the generated CSS?

Comment: I want my scss files to compile into several different css files, not just main one. This is so I can use assetic to only serve the stylesheets that are needed for the specific view. Im thinking about using YUI after sass has already compiled them so that I can then serve the client the specific css files needed as only one file